# Dyanmic dropdown data is loading really slow in PHPusing MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am **fetching some 1000 records precisely from MySQL using PHP in a drop-down box**, data loads on page reload and it is showing in console too, but whenever I click d**ata shows in drop-down really slowly/delay.**

PS: Cannot opt for caching Redis or other.

**SQL Query** is like- `'select user from table'`    //users are 1000

PHP Script:

```
<select name="wname" id="Publication" class="form-control"  required>
              <option value=" ">Select Publication</option>

               <?php
               $select = "";
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
                 ?>

               <option value="<? echo $row['Id']; ?>"<? if($row['Id']==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?>>
                                     <? 
                                       
                                       echo $row['users']; 

                                       ?>
             
      <?php
    }
     ?>
        </option>
            </select>
```

Comment: A 1000 options in a select dropdown is much. Your web browser might be struggling, not to speak about your users who would have to select 1 option out of a 1000.

Comment: there are some data which needs to select from 1000 records, is there any option to perform a drop-down smoothly without any delay or lag! @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Can't help you speed up a `SELECT` that we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a different approach?

You must be render the dropdown as a search box. When your user starts typing, you make an ajax call to the DB, for example at start of 3rd chars.

E.g.

When your user type "sin" you populate with "sineverba" and "sinology", when user continues with "sine" you print only "sineverba" and so on.

Comment: I understand but this approaches call Ajax on every key-up event right?

Comment: This is not a bad idea. You could store the 1000 items in a javascript array and use that instead of an AJAX call. That way the browser doesn't need to render a dropdown with a 1000 items.

Comment: Using an input with an attached datalist would be an easy option, no need to AJAX, lighter on DOM/browser since there's nothing to render.

Comment: @MarkusAO can I see or get any example please ?

Comment: @archana it's a standard HTML feature, examples are everywhere if you search. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist